# Проблемы указания пути в java

Tags: java

Смотрите, у меня есть переменная

```
os = new FileOutputStream(MWBank.DataFolder + "\\Log.txt", true);
```

```
(MWBank.DataFolder - возвращает путь к Desktop/wer/plugins)
```

но по итогу в ubuntu происходит это (на винде этого нет) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не знаю кто такая "путя" поправил на "путь", если вы все-таки имели ввиду неизвестную "путю" то уточните что это такое)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в линуксе разделитель `/`, а не `\`. Вот и получается, что `\` попадает в имя файла. Если программа используется на разных платформах, то и собирать путь надо встроенными средствами, которые знают разницу между системами, а не складывать строку вручную.

Comment: Дополню - `new FileOutputStream(new File(MWBank.DataFolder,"Log.txt"),true)` - так должно работать на любой платформе

Comment: @Sergi не работает( https://i.imgur.com/9xmHFkn.png

Comment: @serverexe проверьте свой код внимательно, похоже вы где-то ещё создаете этот файл